# Erlang gives syntax error on record construction

Tags: syntax, erlang, record, erlang-shell

I have the following code in a module:

```
-module(my_server).

-record(server_opts,
        {port, ip = "127.0.0.1", max_connections = 10}).

Opts1 = #server_opts{port=80}.
```

When I try to compile it in Erlang shell it gives an error like
`syntax error before Opts1`. Any idea what could be the problem with the code above. Please note that the code is taken from the following website:
[Record example in Erlang](http://20bits.com/article/erlang-an-introduction-to-records).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following line:

```
Opts1 = #server_opts{port=80}.
```

Should be contained within a function body:

```
foo() ->
    Opts1 = #server_opts{port=80},
    ...
```

Remember to export the function, so that you can call it from outside the module:

```
-export([test_records/0]).
```

A complete example follows:

```
-module(my_server).

-export([test_records/0]).

-record(server_opts, {port,
                      ip = "127.0.0.1",
                      max_connections = 10}).

test_records() ->
    Opts1 = #server_opts{port=80},
    Opts1#server_opts.port.
```

Comment: Hi Roberto, is this because of avoiding side effects?

Comment: It's because of how modules work in Erlang. A module contains a sequence of attributes (module name, list of exported functions, record definitions, etc.) and of function declarations. To execute a piece of Erlang code, you need an entry point (the function declaration).

Comment: Thanks! :) I wonder why in the example nothing has been mentioned about this. And that is why i was confused with record usages.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, you've thought that `Opts1` is a global constant, but there are no global variables in erlang.

You may use [macro definitions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html#id80492) to have something like global constants (which are actually replaced in compile time):

```
-module(my_server).

-record(server_opts,
        {port,
     ip="127.0.0.1",
     max_connections=10}).

%% macro definition:    
-define(Opts1, #server_opts{port=80}).

%% and use it anywhere in your code:

my_func() ->
     io:format("~p~n",[?Opts1]).
```

P.S.
**Using records from shell.** Assume - you've created file `my_server.hrl` which contain definition of record `server_opts`. First of all you're have to load record definition, using function `rr("name_of_file_with_record_definition")`, after this you're ready to work with records in shell:

```
1> rr("my_record.hrl").
[server_opts]
2> 
2> Opts1 = #server_opts{port=80}.
#server_opts{port = 80,ip = "127.0.0.1",
             max_connections = 10}
3> 
3> Opts1.
#server_opts{port = 80,ip = "127.0.0.1",
             max_connections = 10}
4>
```

Comment: So in general i will always need a function in order to make use of the records; right?

Comment: Yes, you always need wrap execution of code in functions (except erlang shell session, where you may create variables and assign them values without wrapping them to functions - look at edit of my answer).

Comment: I would like to add that in shell you can also define records using command rd: e.g. 5> rd(person, {name, surname}). By the way, as stated above, in erlang your variables must be inside a function..well, if you don't consider erlang macros http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html